# BoneCP throws "SQLException: Connection is closed!" when batch inserting into MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-jdbc, jooq, bonecp

I've been tasked with setting up a project using BoneCP with jOOQ and Spring, but I've run into some difficulties doing so. Doing individual inserts into my MySQL-database works perfectly fine, but doing so with 190 000 objects takes almost 20 minutes, so to speed it up I want to use batch inserts of 100 at a time instead. However, this throws the following exception:

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JDBC transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed!
   at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doRollback(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:288)
   at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:849)
   at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:826)
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:496)
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:266)
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
   at com.theshahin.service.YmsLinkDataService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b9b6e447.create(<generated>)
   at com.theshahin.integration.YmsLinkDataServiceTest.foo(YmsLinkDataServiceTest.java:76)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
   at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
   at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
   at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
   at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
   at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
   at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
   at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
   at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
   at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
   at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
   at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed!
   at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.checkClosed(ConnectionHandle.java:459)
   at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.rollback(ConnectionHandle.java:1270)
   at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doRollback(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:285)
   ... 44 more
```

(It may be worth mentioning that this exception is thrown at the very first batch query, so no queries have been executed prior to it). This is my applicationContext.xml, which is based on the one from jOOQ's tutorial (you can find it here: http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.3/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-with-spring/ ):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.theshahin" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="false"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driver}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60"/>
    <property name="idleMaxAge" value="240"/>
    <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="30"/>
    <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="10"/>
    <property name="partitionCount" value="3"/>
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5"/>
    <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="100"/>
    <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="3"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionAwareDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.jooq.impl.DataSourceConnectionProvider" name="connectionProvider">
    <constructor-arg ref="transactionAwareDataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dsl" class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext">
    <constructor-arg ref="config" />
</bean>

<bean id="jooqToSpringExceptionTransformer" class="com.theshahin.exception.JOOQToSpringExceptionTransformer"/>

<bean class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration" name="config">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="connectionProvider" />
    <constructor-arg index="1"><null /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2"><null /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="3">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteListenerProvider">
                <constructor-arg index="0" ref="jooqToSpringExceptionTransformer"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="4"><null /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="5"><value type="org.jooq.SQLDialect">${jooq.sql.dialect}</value></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="6"><null /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="7"><null /></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

This is the code used for saving the records to the MySQL-database. (Note: the out-commented code is the one I use for individual inserts)

```java
@Service
public class YmsLinkDataService extends BaseService {

    @Transactional
    public void create(List<YmsLinkDataRecord> records) {
        dsl.batchInsert(records).execute();

//        dsl.insertInto(YMS_LINK_DATA, YMS_LINK_DATA.SITE_ID,
//                YMS_LINK_DATA.SITE_TYPE, YMS_LINK_DATA.TIME, YMS_LINK_DATA.URL,
//                YMS_LINK_DATA.KEYWORD).values(linkData.getSiteId(),
//                        YmsLinkDataSiteType.SEARCH, System.currentTimeMillis(),
//                        linkData.getUrl(), linkData.getKeyword()).execute();

    }
}
```

Here's the test case from which the error is thrown (I am aware that it doesn't actually test anything at the moment. I will do that once it successfully saves to DB):

```java
@Test
public void batchInsert() throws InterruptedException, SQLException {
    int batchCount = 0;
    List<YmsLinkDataRecord> batchRecords = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (YmsLinkDataRecord ld : ConfigurationToYmsLinkDataRecord.convert(
            config)) {
        batchCount++;
        batchRecords.add(ld);
        if (batchCount == 100) {
            ldService.create(batchRecords);
            batchRecords.clear();
            batchCount = 0;
        }
    }
    ldService.create(batchRecords);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add the code that is inserting the records. Also have you considered Spring Batch for this scenario?

Comment: No, I have not, actually. I just took jOOQ's word for BoneCP being the fastest connection-pool at the moment, but I'm finding that the lack of available information quite frustrating.

Comment: What has the used datasource to do with the decision to use or not to use Spring Batch?! Those are unrelated questions.

Comment: You'll have to pardon me. Since I have never used nor heard of Spring Batch, I simply assumed that it was a connection pool. Apparently I was wrong.

Comment: What is the type of 'dsl' ? I still would expect you needed to call `create([insert-query-here])` before being able to do batch inserts. But that could be me.

Comment: Its type is `org.jooq.DSLContext`. As I've understood it, jOOQ does that for you, which could explain why there is no such method in its API.

Comment: Isn't the method thrown from your testcase and not the actual code? Can you add the testcase?

Comment: Done! Also, thank you so much for taking your time to help me with this :)

Comment: I switched to Apache Commons DBCP instead, and it works flawlessly. Thank you so much for your help though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Just to be sure, you *are* using the latest versions of all libraries?

Comment: Btw: *"I just took jOOQ's word for BoneCP being the fastest connection-pool at the moment"* I don't think we said that... We actually just took *any* connection pool for our jOOQ/Spring tutorial :-) (not that this would help with your issue, of course...) Given your experience with BoneCP vs. DBCP, I think we might switch as well. Thanks for your patience, and we're sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: You are right, @LukasEder! As a junior developer I was just really confused when using new frameworks and now realized that I'd read that statement on BoneCP's site. And thank you so much for jOOQ, by the way, it's awesome! Can't wait for its community to grow so there'll be even more examples available. Who knows, I might write some myself when we've delivered the finished product to our customer.

Comment: @TheShahin: You're welcome. Thanks to enthusiast users like yourself, the jOOQ community is ever growing. An excellent set of tutorials is currently being written by [Petri Kainulainen](www.petrikainulainen.net/tag/jooq/) (which we based our Spring tutorial upon). If you publish something, we'll certainly feature you on our blog / Twitter / [Community](http://www.jooq.org/community) website. We also ship [stickers](http://www.jooq.org/img/sticker-jooq-sql-rockstar.png) for outstanding contributions :-)

Answer (score 4):

BoneCP has a rather interesting "feature" : if query fails with "fatal" error code pool will close ALL connections and become unusable. As far as I remember I had a similar issue when MySQL was failing with "HY00" error due to something like missing column

Relevant piece of code : https://github.com/wwadge/bonecp/blob/master/bonecp/src/main/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/ConnectionHandle.java#L182

It seems that "HY00" is no longer deemed fatatl in the latest version

Comment: this has saved me a bunch of time wondering why Ingres connections are all coming back "closed" on first acquisition. Be warned BoneCP doesn't play nice with Ingres either.